# ORA-01017: invalid username/password; logon denied is thrown by the Oracle 12c "Database Configuration Assistant" tool

Tags: oracle12c

I'm encountering an "invalid username/password" error when trying to create a pluggable database in the container database with Oracle 12c. The error occurs when the "Database Configuration Assistant" tries to load the information of the container database ORCL. Please find below a screenshot of the error:

[dbcaError](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xb5WL.png)

As you can notice the fields "Username" and "Password" are grayed out. I can access the OCRL database by using sqlplus (sqlplus / as sysdba).

I can see the following exception in the log file C:\oracle12c\userName\cfgtoollogs\dbca\dbcaui.log

---# Begin Stacktrace #---------------------------
ID: oracle.install.commons.util.exception.DefaultErrorAdvisor:1824
oracle.sysman.assistants.util.sqlEngine.SQLFatalErrorException: ORA-01017: invalid username/password; logon denied

```
at oracle.sysman.assistants.util.sqlEngine.SQLEngine.executeImpl(SQLEngine.java:1739)
at oracle.sysman.assistants.util.sqlEngine.SQLEngine.connect(SQLEngine.java:987)
at oracle.sysman.assistants.util.PluggableDatabaseUtils.isCDB(PluggableDatabaseUtils.java:278)
at oracle.sysman.assistants.dbca.wizard.view.DatabaseListPage.doValidate(DatabaseListPage.java:911)
at oracle.sysman.assistants.util.wizard.WizardPanel.validate(WizardPanel.java:269)
at oracle.install.commons.flow.validation.ValidationHelper.validateView(ValidationHelper.java:168)
at oracle.install.commons.flow.AbstractFlowExecutor.validate(AbstractFlowExecutor.java:391)
at oracle.install.commons.flow.AbstractFlowExecutor.leaveVertex(AbstractFlowExecutor.java:644)
at oracle.install.commons.flow.AbstractFlowExecutor.transition(AbstractFlowExecutor.java:336)
at oracle.install.commons.flow.AbstractFlowExecutor.nextState(AbstractFlowExecutor.java:276)
at oracle.install.commons.flow.AbstractFlowExecutor.nextViewState(AbstractFlowExecutor.java:235)
at oracle.install.commons.flow.DefaultFlowNavigator.goForward(DefaultFlowNavigator.java:58)
at oracle.install.commons.flow.jewt.FlowWizard$1.run(FlowWizard.java:137)
at oracle.install.commons.flow.jewt.FlowWizard$TransitionManager$1.run(FlowWizard.java:113)
at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:439)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:303)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:138)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:895)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:918)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:682)
```

Any idea on how to solve the problem?

Thanks.

**UPDATE**

This is the content of my tnsnames.ora 
C:\oracle12c\icirillo\product\12.1.0\dbhome_1\NETWORK\ADMIN\tnsnames.ora

```
# tnsnames.ora Network Configuration File: C:\oracle12c\icirillo\product\12.1.0\dbhome_1\network\admin\tnsnames.ora
# Generated by Oracle configuration tools.

LISTENER_ORCL =
  (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = localhost)(PORT = 1522))


ORACLR_CONNECTION_DATA =
  (DESCRIPTION =
    (ADDRESS_LIST =
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = IPC)(KEY = EXTPROC1522))
    )
    (CONNECT_DATA =
      (SID = CLRExtProc)
      (PRESENTATION = RO)
    )
  )

ORCL =
  (DESCRIPTION =
    (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = localhost)(PORT = 1522))
    (CONNECT_DATA =
      (SERVER = DEDICATED)
      (SERVICE_NAME = orcl.ivano.mydomain.net)
      #(SERVICE_NAME = ORCL)
    )
  )
```

**UPDATE 2**

I figured out another thing. If in the DBCA I select "Delete database" (instead of "Manage Pluggable Database-->create Pluggable database") when I reach the database list form (the one in the image above) and then I click on next, I do not encounter the same issue, I can navigate to the next form without any issue (no error messages are displayed).

**UPDATE 3**
When looking at the installation log I could notice a problem with disk space. Maybe this could have corrupted something. I will try to reinstall.

```
RMAN-00571: ===========================================================
RMAN-00569: =============== ERROR MESSAGE STACK FOLLOWS ===============
RMAN-00571: ===========================================================
RMAN-03002: failure of restore command at 05/18/2017 17:38:43
ORA-19870: error while restoring backup piece C:\ORACLE12C\ICIRILLO\PRODUCT\12.1.0\DBHOME_1\ASSISTANTS\DBCA\TEMPLATES\SAMPLESCHEMA.DFB
ORA-19504: failed to create file "C:\ORACLE12C\ICIRILLO\ORADATA\ORCL\PDBORCL\EXAMPLE01.DBF"
ORA-27044: unable to write the header block of file
OSD-04008: WriteFile() failure, unable to write to file
O/S-Error: (OS 112) There is not enough space on the disk.
RMAN> 
echo set on

[Thread-7] [ 2017-05-18 17:38:45.110 CEST ] [RmanFileRestorer.restoreFiles:222]  reset _catalog_foreign_restore
[Thread-7] [ 2017-05-18 17:38:45.220 CEST ] [PlugDatabaseStep.executeImpl:240]  ERROR :oracle.sysman.assistants.dbca.backend.storage.FileRestoreException: Error while restoring PDB backup piece
[Thread-7] [ 2017-05-18 17:38:45.220 CEST ] [BasicStep.configureSettings:353]  messageHandler being set=oracle.sysman.assistants.util.InteractiveMessageHandler@2f26f304
[Thread-7] [ 2017-05-18 17:38:45.220 CEST ] [CreatePDBAfterCDBCreationStep.executeImpl:376]  Error while restoring PDB backup piece
[Thread-7] [ 2017-05-18 17:38:45.220 CEST ] [CreatePDBAfterCDBCreationStep.executeImpl:377]  Pluggable Database pdborcl creation failed
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem in two steps.

1. During my first installation I was using an existent Windows account which was part of the Administrators group and according to the Oracle documentation this could have caused some problems so I decided to create a new dedicated Oracle account during the Oracle installation. When I did that I encountered a different problem when the installer launched oradim: `error in process:...\bin\oradim.exe. Enter password for Oracle service user: DIM-00019: create service error. O/S-Error: (OS 87) The parameter is incorrect.`
2. After that I could figure out that the oradim error can occur if installing Oracle 12c on windows server which is a domain controller (and it was the case, I was using Windows Server 2012 R2 domain controller). Please refer to the following links:

   - http://dbaforums.org/oracle/index.php?showtopic=24124
   - https://www.experts-exchange.com/questions/21110717/creating-a-database-using-DBCA-on-Oracle-10g-running-on-Windows-2003-Server.html

I then installed Oracle 12c on Windows 7 and all problems were solved.

Answer (score 0):

For the connection which works: `sqlplus / as sysdba` is an OS authentication which uses `IPC` or `BEQ`.

For the connection which doesn't work:

1. DBCA uses 
   Look at the entry in `listener.ora` for CDB ROOT connection, mostly it will be like `inst1_local`
2. For the SYS user we need to give the container to which it should connect, so we need to give the listerner entry pointing to CDB ROOT. In your case probably `sys@inst1_local` will be the user name

Comment: Thanks! but not sure I understand what to do :) For point 1: I have updated my question with the content of my listener.ora. I do not see anything like `inst1_local`. For point 2: I presume you are refferring to sqlplus.

Comment: @IvanoCirillo Sorry, its tnsnames.ora not listener.ora

Comment: OK. Thanks. So I have updated my question with tnsnames.ora. As you can notice I already tried to change the service name (the commented line was my test) but it didn't solve the problem. Would you know what is wrong? WIth the DBCA graphical tool I cannot specifiy username and password. Did you look at the provided screenshot? "Username" and "password" fields are grayed out. Thanks.